# Windows update install failing within a virtual machine for a particular update

Tags: windows-update

I have a virtual machine with XP and Visual Studio and have windows update working fine for most updates.

When I try to install the security update (Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 KB971092)  related to Visual Studio it fails?

Any ideas why?

Suggestions to install it a different way/outside of Windows update?

Comment: What Service Pack is XP running? What virtualization platform are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update was failing due to lack of disk space.

Answer (score 1):

Check Event Viewer for more detailed errors...

You can try downloading the [KB971092](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=294de390-3c94-49fb-a014-9a38580e64cb) and installing it manually.  You should get some sort of error to help you troubleshoot further.